# Can I stick speakers to the parcel shelf without drilling or making holes?

Tags: audio, speakers

My parcel shelf is about 5mm thick, and I would like to add some small speakers to it.

I don't want to drill or make holes in the shelf, as I want it to look original from the top, and be able to return it to original when I sell the car.

Is there any way I can attach speakers to the parcel shelf without drilling?

If it helps, I can include some pictures.

Comment: You can always put surface mount speakers on there, I'd assume.

Comment: Can you drill several small holes that remain covered by the cloth of the shelf?  Sure you might not one big giant hole, but an array of small holes will pass the sound, probably to a favorable degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Paulster suggested surface mount speakers - these would work well but the sound quality isn't going to be as good as normal speakers.  Parcel shelfs tend to be made of compressed fibre now which is flexible and flimsy for speaker applications. In the past I have made a parcel shelf out of 12-18mm thick High Density Fibreboard and reinforced it with a cross member underneath to stop it sagging in the middle, then mounted the speakers to that.

The added benefit of doing this was the original parcel shelf was left intact for when I came to sell the car.

Note: this was for a hatchback in the UK and may not suit all car types.